# Imported account from privatenode shows loose and 0 balance

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, accounts, balances

I have created my private node with the following config:

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 65536,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "20000",
    "gasLimit": "210000",
    "alloc": {
    "c8Caa71C16299B40B8579742a27EE53162886040": { "balance": "1000000000" },
    "60fDF758ed3549D550A52f2044B43aadf782aA4E": { "balance": "2000000000" }
    }
}
```

After that import the accounts in Geth using:

```
web3.personal.importRawKey("7c7f89b68b7a549a45856ae569997f98c4fba8f3272e90df1cf010f093d655e6", "abcd1234")
web3.personal.importRawKey("6a684c74467fb7b1d551968bf96eee7c1638a2537631372ca8c5c88837a50e8d", "abcd1234")
```

(the passphrase is correct)

Get balance shows the correct value;

```
> eth.getBalance("0x60fDF758ed3549D550A52f2044B43aadf782aA4E")
2000000000
> eth.getBalance("0xc8Caa71C16299B40B8579742a27EE53162886040")
1000000000
```

When I try to import the above accounts again using Metamask with their private keys (shown above).

Metamask shows that the accounts are loose, and with 0 balance.

Can anyone explain what I had did wrongly? Thanks

Comment: Is metamask set to the correct network?

Comment: Yes correctly set to my private network

Comment: Answer to my own question. Metamask now changed the name to *imported* instead of *loose*. I think that makes more sense now. And 0 balance was because the amount that I entered were just too small.

Answer (score 1):

The Balances you allocated to the wallets are in wei and very small that's why metamask is showing it 0. Allocate multiple of 1000000000000000000(1 Eth) and it will show in metamask.